# Entity Framework 4 Linq Include not loading collections

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, nopcommerce

I have a problem understanding and working with the Include command, primarily when working on a nopCommerce 1.9 site, but I have the same problem everywhere. I have searched the net, and on stackoverflow, but can't seem to find anyone else having the same problem, so I guess it's just me that is getting this wrong.

I think that the problem is very simple, but plainly: When I include the child entities when querying the parent entity, EF loads all of the entities, but not the collection which means that when I try and access the collection, EF goes back to the database to load the collection.

To clarify, consider the following:

```
var products = (from p in _context.Products.Include("NpProductVariants") select p).ToList();

var productvariant = products.ProductVariants[2]; //Loads the NpProductVariants collection
```

I think that the additional fetch is superflous, indeed, if I create an object to hold the navigation collection and code using the holder, I can avoid further fetches, but this is annoying i.e.

```
var products = (from p in _context.Products.Include("NpProductVariants") select new productholder() { product = p, variants = p.NpProductVariants }).ToList();
```

This proves that the collection is available during query execution because I can store it, but it doesn't automatically appear as attached to the ObjectContext until I try and access properties which requires an extra query.

I think that the problem is clear, but what am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Mark

Comment: in first code : you Include `NpProductVariants`, then use products.`ProductVariants[2]`. And you didn't include any ProductVariants... So, which one do you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including `"NpProductVariants"`, but you are accessing `ProductVariants`.

There are two things you can do, depending on your actual EF model:

1. Change the `Include` to `"ProductVariants"`:

   ```
   var products = _context.Products.Include("ProductVariants");
   ```
2. Change the property you access to `NpProductVariants`:

   ```
   var productvariant = products.NpProductVariants[2];
   ```

Comment: Not that clear. In first part of code it's ProductVariants, in second it's NpProductVariants... Or they are two navigation properties ! Cause if NpProductVariants did not exist, the query would raise an error, which doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: Indeed, that slipped my attention. I would like to keep my answer though, because it is not clear that it *doesn't* solve the problem. Feedback from the OP would be nice.

Comment: I certainly didn't ask you to remove it, wouldn't have notice this without your answer...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: Thanks for clarification. I wasn't sure if your first comment implied a wish for removal or not.

Comment: Hi, NpProductVariants is a navigation property. If I use "ProductVariants" as in .Include("ProductVariants"), I get an error that it isn't a navigation property.

Comment: Also I generally use ProductVariants in code. I had presumed that it simply wrapped NpProductVariants, but that appears not to be the case.

Comment: The answer by Daniel Hilgarth is correct, but for nopCommerce 1.9 people, it is probably useful to know that the "ProductVariants" property is not just a wrapper for "NpProductVariants". It actually executes a search for the given ProductID accross all ProductVariants. Not for use in your own queries - but at least I know the difference now! Thanks.